# how to handle 404 redirect if non www is redirected to www

Tags: node.js, express

I'm using Node.js and I want to render 404 page if route doesn't exist but the problem is I also redirected my webpage from non-www to www. Below is the code I used for non-www to www redirect.

```
app.all(/.*/, function(req, res, next) {
    var host = req.header("host");
    if (host.match(/^www\..*/i))
        next();
    else
        res.redirect(301, "http://www." + host);
});
```

I also want a 404 error handling with this. I read many post regarding this but none of them help me. How to do it.

Backend technology used is Node.js

Comment: I hate that I'm saying this, because I always hate this type of answer, but: I don't think you really want to do this.  What happens if you test your code using "localhost"?  Or a numeric IP address?  This is better left to other mechanisms, such as an apache redirect or something.

Comment: I understand what you're trying to say. I'm not going to implement this way for sure but for sake of knowledge I want to know actually how to do it.